# For web email authentication with the link to signup/in - Which is the best replacement of FB Account Kit? Twilio or Firebase or something?

Tags: facebook, authentication, replace, account

On March 9, 2020, Account Kit will be deprecated and will no longer function. I'm looking for a solution that can smoothly replace FB account kit, easy to implement and have a similar UX for end user is a plus. Thanks you!